# Displaying both text and icons in gridview

Tags: android

I want to display the icons in grid view and also text heading for that icon just below it.
can some one help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You are supplying an `Adapter` to the `GridView`. Have that `Adapter` return `Views` for the cells that have icons "and also text heading for that icon just below it". You might use a vertical `LinearLayout` with an `ImageView` and `TextView` children, for example.

[Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that shows how to do this sort of thing for a `ListView` -- the same technique holds for `GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are beggining in Android like me, I found out that the simplest thing to start with is to:

1) Set each grid to contain a textview

2) Set background (icons in your case) to each textview; plus add the text.

Like:

```
//textview is a the textview in the cells
textview.setBackgroundResource(<your icon resource>);
```

The text is added and modified normally:

```
textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
textview.setTextAppearance(mContext, R.<style xml>);
textview.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

You'd most likely need to properly set the text position and color so you have a readable result.
Then you may also set the background properties (you can check textview methods)